# How to re-generate test directory in rails6 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing

I want to write integration and system tests for my Rails app. Maybe I have accidentally deleted the `test` folder after generating app or have written it with the `-t` flag.

When I want to run `rails g integration_test board_flow` command nothing happens:

```
rails generate integration_test board_flow
DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from <main> at /home/procy/my-app-name/config/application.rb:20)
Deprecation warning: Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean).
This will be rejected in the future unless you explicitly pass the options `check_default_type: false` or call `allow_incompatible_default_type!` in your code
You can silence deprecations warning by setting the environment variable THOR_SILENCE_DEPRECATION
```

I have not created any tests for this app before (unit-tests, etc.)

What should I do?

Comment: I'd try to create another dummy rails project in a different location, then copy over the `./test` directory. After that I'd try to generate the integration test again.

Comment: Well, It could help, but I think, models wouldn't be match with my app :/

Comment: The `./test` directory only contains boilerplate code after creating a new project. You mentioned that you haven't created any tests before anyway, so by copying that boilerplate stuff you shouldn't be losing anything.

Comment: Thanks, I have make another app this the same and just copied the ```test``` folder. Just, I thought that I could remake it by ```generate``` command, but, anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try `rails g test_unit:integration NameOfTheTest`

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest workaround is create two rails app with same name but in different location, one with `-T` flag to ignore test and other without `-T` flag.

Then compare both project directories with tools like [meld](https://meldmerge.org/) to visually spot the difference between to apps. Copy required files and configuration from the project generated without `-T` project into your project.